# Click and open form

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have form structure. With the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/6GHmM/

And when click h1 tag, open form via accordion. I tired but not working. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the event to the `h1` tag and the `div` elements are **not** children but siblings to the `h1` tag.

Also your HTML needs fixing or the code won't work, you forgot the `h1` closing tag.

Change HTML:

```
// From
<h1>CLICK AND OPEN<h1>

// To
<h1>CLICK AND OPEN</h1>
```

Then update your script to use siblings instead of children and add the missing `event` parameter or `event.stopPropagation()` will throw an error:

```
$('.uyeform h1').click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle('300');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6GHmM/2/) - slideToggle() siblings

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GHmM/11/)**. Please have a look.

```
$('div.input').hide();
$('.uyeform h1').click(function() {
    $('div.input').slideToggle('300');
    event.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Comment: The fiddle slide-toggles the complete form which is a big assumption. Instead of changing the intend, just fixing the original fiddle would suffice. Also, please post the relevant code into ther answer as it is of no use to anyone in the future when link-rot sets in on the linked fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few problems. First, you are not including the jquery library.
Then you are saying `event.stopPropagation` but even was never defined. Also, `h1` has no children

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GHmM/5/) and see if it meets your requirements